# CollapsingToolbarLayout ImageView is not scrollable

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-scrollview, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Using [cheesesquare - android support library example](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) is it possible to make the Header `ImageView` scroll-able?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" 
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            ...
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    ....
```

**Notice** that i've added added `android:fillViewport="true"` to `NestedScrollView` and also **added** `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"` to 
the `ImageView` but when trying to scroll from the `ImageView` nothing happens.

Comment: I have the same problem; however, it is because my image fills in the entire screen. So there is nothing I can scroll. I  created a workaround to allow scrolling via setting the bottom margin. However, this does not allow me to scroll the ImageView

Answer (score 4):

OK, I did some research in the bug reports, and **this is a known bug within the `Design Support Library`**.

[Check out the bug report here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176673&q=collapsingToolbarLayout%20scroll&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

### Excerpt

> I have taken a look at the implementation that backs `CoordinatorLayout`/`AppBarLayout`/the `Behavior` classes etc. The `AppBarLayout` uses the behaviour defined in `AppBarLayout.Behavior` by default. This extends `ViewOffsetBehavior` which in turn extends `Behavior`. The base `Behavior` class has the methods `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `onTouchEvent()`, both of which return false (meaning "we don't want to handle touch events"). These methods are not overridden by either `ViewOffsetBehavior` or `AppBarLayout.Behavior`, meaning that the touch is left unhandled - which is why it does nothing.
>
> A possible workaround for third-party developers would be to extend `AppBarLayout.Behavior` and implement `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `onTouchEvent()` and manipulate the app bar accordingly.

### Videos

These show the current and intended behavior. These are also from the bug report.

- https://youtu.be/xWadOVEaTSY
- https://youtu.be/J8ITp6RusZo

Comment: Thanks for your answer Christopher. I voted it up (-:

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround by embedding the imageView in a NestedScrollView:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <ImageView
                tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
                tools:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:minHeight="200dp"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

But I haven't tested it in prod as I met another issue with the fling to top gesture which is interrupted when the recyclerview reaches the top ( as explained in the bug report).

Answer (score 0):

From testing this on support library 23.1.1, this issue seems to have been fixed.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

You can now put into your CollapsingToolbarLayout anything, ImageView, RelativeLayout, TextView and it will scroll as intended.

Comment: It works until you add bottom sheet layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939982/scrolling-is-not-working-with-coordinatorlayout-parallax-image-bottomsheetla/36968467#36968467